# Include external files for modular tests

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario where I would like to test many different sites using one base Test Plan. All of those sites makes roughly the same calls (a shopping scenario), but some sites makes additional calls.

To make it simple, let's say I have two sites to test, site A and site B. Each test site has a test folder containing their custom external plans. Right now I have a "base" Test Plan, let's call it TP, and one external file, let's call that EP (External Plan) **only in site A**. In site B I have **no external files** (because it does not have any additional calls).

I tried calling the EP for site A, using an `Include Controller`, from TP and that works fine, but when I run TP against site B the external file (EP) does not exist and the test will not even start.

The problem is that JMeter only runs when the external file actually exist on the path (you can not even *start* the test if `Include Controller` is not passed a valid file.

My goal is to make this scenario module in a way that you add an external file to each site's test-folder for each "special call" that is made. If the site in question has no "special calls", no external file should be added. If we add a new site, we should not have to add external files to all other sites!

For example, having an option for `Include Controller` like `ignore missing file` would help immensely, but alas there is no such option.

How can I make my scenario modular with JMeter?

Comment: make empty "default" plan for each site?

Comment: Can't do that. If something changes (and it will) in the default plan, I would have to change that on all sites.